HDMI/DP over CAT from PCIe card using output from GPU
I have a bunch of servers rendering realtime graphics using an NVidia GPUs, I want to display these graphics on a video wall elsewhere in the building. Sending the signal over cat is fine, using Dante or HDBaseT is fine (no preference). Using extender modules is fine.
However to simplify the rack I'd rather use PCIe cards. I'm not clear on how a HDBT/Dante PCIe card works wrt the GPU. Can I send the GPU output over the cat using a PCIe transmitter card? Do I need a specific kind of card?

Maybe? This is a pretty specialized system, it seems, and I'd guess you'll need to look at the specs and capabilities of the hardware you're looking at and comparing that to your needs.

@music2myear I appreciate that but it's beyond me to search every transmitter card and read through all the specs  The few I did read through didn't explain if they can output from GPU, and I couldn't find any info online. Perhaps I could buy a few different cards and start testing them individually, but I imagine real time graphics over CAT is not too unusual, so someone must already have experience with transmitter cards - at least enough to say if it's possible or not.
